# How can I set oh my zsh to be my default shell?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, zsh

I'm using Hyper as my terminal application and I just installed Oh My Zsh via curl. I'd like it to be my default shell environment but for some reason whenever I restart Hyper I have to run the `zsh` command to get to Oh My Zsh. Is this normal?

Comment: `oh-my-zsh` is not a shell. There is a similar toolset for bash, called (not surprisingly) [_oh-my-bash_](https://ohmybash.nntoan.com/). I have no idea how well it compares to the zsh version. If you like oh-my-zsh, why not switching your interactive shell to zsh? Although different from bash in severaly ways, it is sufficiently similar that you will feel at home soon.

Comment: We’ve got quite a few questions covering how to set `zsh` as the default shell. What is “Hyper” and why isn’t it following the system might be the question here.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it’s somewhat normal since there’s a bug and some people aren’t restarting after changing the system shell to `zsh` as described below and [in the hyper documents](https://github.com/vercel/hyper/issues/4266).

You should be able to make the switch to have it restart though. One note, before the fix is addressed - Oh My Zsh isn’t a shell.  It’s a set of ZSH shell customizations like creating a colorful and grphical prompt or autocompletion and even file selection. The shell is the bus and “omz” is a specific seat arrangement, paint and stylings on the bus that get added to the generic “bus”.

If you have to run `zsh` to get the cusomizations, then you’re not in the ZSH shell; likely you’re in Bash.  You can check your current shell with the commands

```
$ echo $SHELL

or

$ echo $0
```

What you need to do is change your default shell.  As soon as this command is done, check it’s permanent by restarting your OS and repeat the tests above.

```
$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

You can also do this via the GUI by going to *System Preferences > Users & Groups* Then, while holding <kbd>Control</kbd> click on the user you want to edit and click on *Advanced Options*.  In the “Login Shell” field, select the shell you want to use - */bin/zsh* for for the ZSH shell.

[image: User Advanced Options]

---

A piece of friendly advice...  Oh My Zsh is a fun, colorful, and even productive add-on for Zsh that makes lots of changes and adds lots of scripts and functions to your Zsh environment.  I don’t recommend this for novices.  It’s always better to gain some experience in the shell environment and see how things work before installing things like this.

Comment: In Terminal it defaults to zsh. So I found this issue thread and it seems to be the same thing I'm experiencing: https://github.com/vercel/hyper/issues/4266

Comment: The last comment there mentions fully logging out and back in, that did seem to fix it for me. Hyper is defaulting to zsh now, although it is printing a `%` in the first line on startup for some reason. Not a big deal though

Comment: still says /bin/sh for me on mac

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

You’ll need to log out, then log back in for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Would this work on macOS as well?

Comment: Yes should work

Answer (score -1):

just go to .bashrc file, add "exec /bin/zsh" at the very bottom of the line
save and run "source ~/.bashrc", it will work

Comment: How does this set the default shell?

Comment: Creative use of bash to fake out the system and choose zsh later…