# Way to keep track of successful commands on command line?

Tags: terminal, command-line, iterm, zsh

Usually I just copy/paste successful actions I do on the command line into a text file. That's a bit of an error prone and cumbersome process and I sometimes forget to do it.

Do you know of a way to automatically log commands that return successfully (I'm thinking of things like cmake, make etc. but also basic commands like `cd`) to a text file in order to keep a record of how you managed to finally successfully set up your environment to compile that one stubborn piece of code? For instance...

I'm on a MacBook Pro, MacOS Catalina, using iTerm2 with `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh` extension, as well as `powerlevel10k`.

Comment: All _commands_ are already being recorded in **~/.zsh_history**. This of course includes ones that did not complete successfully, but at least you have a record.

Comment: That's basically the point. I only want to record those that are successful. That can be based on the exit code (so basically, record if exit code == 0), I'd be fine with that.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you know of a way to automatically log commands that return successfully ... in order to keep a record of how you managed to finally successfully set up your environment to compile that one stubborn piece of code?

You first need to answer the question *What constitutes a successful command?*

You're probably thinking "that's easy!  One that works and exits with a 0 code!"  To get a better perspective of that, you need to define what a *failed command* is.  The broadest of definitions will be *any command that has an exit code of not zero*.  Does that mean the command has failed?

No.  It doesn't.  Commands fail for any number of reasons and that doesn't mean what you typed was in error.  Let's use a very simple example:  `ssh`.  If you connect to a remote server and exit cleanly (type `exit` when your done), you will get an exit status of zero (0).  However, if you `poweroff` the machine, you will get an exit status of one (1) when the connections is broken.

Did your command fail?

Try it.  Connect via SSH to any remote.  Exit cleanly then issue the command `echo $?`.  Do it again and then issue `poweroff` or kill your session on the remote and issue the echo command again.

I also use Zsh and I created a custom prompt that prefaces my prompt with  a green check [image: green check] or a "red X" [image: red x] depending on whether the last command failed or not.

Here's a sample with the SSH example used above.

[image: Green Check Prompt]

[image: Red X Prompt]

Did the command actually fail?  No, it didn't but the result generated an error code because something in the *process* failed.  This holds true for the commands you issue compiling software as well.  **Your command can be syntactically perfect, but the compile will still fail because you have an error in your code.** Did you want that command ignored?

#### BASH_COMMAND Environment Variable

Out of curiosity, I investigated this and it’s not a trivial thing to do.  You cannot use `history` because it’s designed to be *interactive* and not scripted.

In Bash, there is an environment varialbe called [$BASH_COMMAND](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-BASH_005fCOMMAND).  It’s the command that is about to be or is being executed unless the command was called from a [Trap](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Signals), then its the command executing at the time of the trap.

In order to make use of this, you would have to execute all of your commands within a DEBUG trap:

```
trap ‘prev_command=$thiscmd; thiscmd=$BASH_CMD’ DEBUG
mycommand
if $? -eq 0; echo $prev_command >> somefile.txt; else echo “Command failed”; fi
```

This would be the logic, but in all practicality, **it doesn’t work because you have to execute your command within a trap.**

I haven’t found an equivalent in Zsh (yet... but I doubt I’ll continue my research).

#### Zsh Addons

> I'm on a MacBook Pro, MacOS Catalina, using iTerm2 with zsh and oh-my-zsh extension, as well as powerlevel10k.

I'm not a fan of these things [especially for the novice user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/399991/119271).  You're bringing in lots of extra complexity and add-ons to prettify your command prompt and shell environment.  I encourage folks actually learn how to do this manually so you understand the underpinnings of your system.

The code for my above example is actually very simple:

```
PROMPT="%(?.%F{green}✓.%F{red})%fallan@%m %F{blue}%1~ %f%# "
```

In fact, I create a simple function (in `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bash_profile) for when I have to cut/paste terminal output to public forums like this:

```
# (Re)sets the prompt on the fly
setprompt() {

  case "$1" in
    se) # Obfuscates username to "allan" for StackExchange posts
        PROMPT="%(?.%F{green}✓.%F{red})%fallan@%m %F{blue}%1~ %f%# "
        ;;
    *)  # Default is to set the prompt back to the original
        PROMPT=' %(?.%F{green}✓.%F{red})%f%n@%m %F{blue}%1~ %f%# '
    ;;
  esac
}
```

Bottom line, this really isn’t feasible.

Avoid all those add-ons.  It's just wrapping.  Learn to use the core shell first, then add things as you go.  This will help you in actually learning the system.  You're looking for shortcuts to things and this will actually hinder your effectiveness.

#### TL;DR

**Don't do this.**  A command that failed isn't necessarily a bad command.  You can very easily "ignore" a perfectly good command because it failed due to an issue not related to the command itself.

> Usually I just copy/paste successful actions I do on the command line into a text file. That's a bit of an error prone and cumbersome process and I sometimes forget to do it.

If you're finding copy/pasting to be error prone, you're doing it wrong.  If it's cumbersome and you forget, then rethink your workflow.  I have OneNote open on my second monitor at all times so I can refer to and take notes as soon as I need to. Find a flow that works for you.  The built in shell history isn't a substitute for good note taking.

Not only is this not a good practice overall, it’s not feasible at due to how you would go about *capturing* the last successful command.

Comment: A bit about my background maybe: I consider myself a pro user who knows what's going on in the background (at least two decades of experience on Linux/Unix/POSIX systems). For me it would just be a convenience thing of replacing "ah that has worked, copy it, paste it into a text file" with automation. I am perfectly aware that error codes are only evidence, not necessarily proof of success. Alternatively I could imagine a shortcut command to just log the last issued command line into a file. It might admittedly be too much of an edge case, an individual challenge for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Then, based in your last comment, how would this script/function/application define a successful command?  You should be able to define that to accomplish your goal

Comment: Well, in the first iteration for me it would be totally fine if the script/application defined success as exit code = 0. That's it. I, personally, don't need more than that for now. It does not need to be able to perfectly detect an all-embracing success from the very start.

Answer (score 1):

As user3439894 stated in the comment already, there is a history file recording all commands issued on the command line regardless of success or failure.  This list of commands is finite, however, and will toss off the oldest command after having issued a number of commands.  I have not checked, but I think on average that would be somewhere between 500-1000 commands (maybe more).

Whether a command was successful or not is not stored beyond the last command given.  The exit code of the last command can be retrieved using the `$?` variable (non-zero is meant to indicate that an error occurred).

The reason this is not stored for longer is that in almost all cases it would not be useful.

Example:

1. You opened Terminal just now and find yourself in your home directory (typically indicated by a simple tilde `~`).
2. Now you issue `cd Downloads`, which under normal circumstances shall be a successfully issued command.
3. Finding yourself in `Downloads` now, you can try to recall the last command by pressing the up-arrow key and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> one more time.
4. However now, unless you manually created another directory called `Downloads` inside your `Downloads` directory, you will see that this time the command will fail.

So, in order to have a useful list of commands which were successfully issued, you would need to also record the environment, which includes the current path you were located in, the files which were available at the time you issued the command as well as their content and possibly other things I may have forgotten to list.

You therefore see that such a list is impossible to obtain or even worse to maintain.

If this is for you to learn how zsh works, it is better to look through manpages or online resources rather than tediously record successfully run commands along with their arguments in a text file as the next time you run them, they may no longer be successful or provide results you would not expect, effectively hampering your learning experience by confusing you.

Comment: My intention is to keep track of shorter sequences of commands that lead to, for example, a successful build of some binary, ignoring everything that I tried in between that did not work. That protocol can start at a specific point, say, right before a `git clone` command and stop when the build was finally successful (both manually if necessary). It would be of help to reconstruct what has been done in order to build the binary, not necessarily a means to  auto-generate shell scripts. I'd be fine with that. I think that's one valid use case for such a feature.

Comment: Sorry to crush your dreams here, but it unfortunately does not change anything I mentioned in my answer.  Any command issued is depending on too many variables to be successful.  So, a manual short list where you exactly know what the situation was may be feasible.  Alternatively, a simple list of commands you used as a mnemonic bridge.  You can create scripts to shorten what you wrote on the command-line, but even that is not a guarantee that the command will run successfully the next time since the situation you call it up may have changed.

Comment: Best way really is to learn the meaning of the commands and their arguments, so that you know what you type.  Then there is no need for an elaborate list to begin with as you would spot errors in a misfired command by simply revisiting it.